# Medoo echo values from Select

Tags: php, pdo, medoo

Using Medoo how do I echo the values from the select query currently this is what I am doing using the example from the docs.

```
$data = $database->select('names', [
'name','nameId'
], [
'nameId' => 50
]);

echo json_encode($data);
```

the result is:

```
[{"name":"Allen","nameId":"50"}]
```

How can I echo each one without json_encode?

I have tried:

```
$data['name']
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's one row you're looking to fetch, use Get instead of Select

```
      $names = $db->get('names',['name','nameId'],['nameId'=>50]);
```

then use

```
      $name = $names['name'];
      $nameId = $names['nameId'];
```

although you don't need the nameId since your condition is based on it so simply:

```
      $name = $db->get('names','name',['nameId'=>50]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop and print.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // echo code here...
    // echo $row['name'];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Was hoping avoid looping just for a single row.

Comment: $data[0][‘name’]